# How to create a colored dome background in CSS

Tags: css

Currently my website looks like this when I apply `border-radius` property to the colored div:
[image: Undesired]

But I want to it to look like this:

[image: Desired]

I know by adjusting border-radius is not enough, any idea how I can achieve the above??

PS: *Using image background is not feasible in my case*

Comment: Would using a background image instead not feasible?

Comment: good point @Swellar! unfortunately it wouldn't be feasible in my case.

Comment: I see. Sometimes, it is faster to just create an image rather than doing complicated `css`. Although too bad it is not applicable to you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dome requires a negative left and right margin and the border radius should be imroved. That should do the trick. Wrapping it in an `overflow: hidden` container prevents a horizontal scrollbar.

```css
.dome {
  margin: 10% -25% 0; 
  border-top-left-radius: 100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 100%; 
  padding-bottom: 50%;
}
.gradientbg {
  /* gradient generated with http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ using #81badd and #ae85ff*/
  background: rgb(129,186,221);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(129,186,221,1) 0%, rgba(174,133,255,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(129,186,221,1) 0%,rgba(174,133,255,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(129,186,221,1) 0%,rgba(174,133,255,1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#81badd', endColorstr='#ae85ff',GradientType=0 );
}
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="dome gradientbg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: might need overflow-x hidden?

Comment: Good point! I have added that.

Comment: Exactly what I need! In my case it would be `border-top-left-radius` and `border-top-right-radius` since I do not need the bottom corners to be curvy.

Comment: This is too complicated. The `200%` radius does nothing `100%` wouldn't achieve, and using `overflow:hidden` and negative margins creates the potential for a bunch of other issues that are totally unnecessary when you just write more than one border-radius value. This solution also requires an unnecessary wrapper element.

Comment: @LirenYeo Great! I just replaced the border-radius with a top-left and top-right border radius, because that is a much cleaner solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Bmd Good points... I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing you need to achieve this effect is a % radius on the top-left and top-right corners, which you can achieve with separate declarations of `border-top-left-radius:100%` and `border-top-right-radius:100%`, or with a combined declaration of `border-radius:100% 100% 0 0` where the first '100%' refers to the top-left, the second '100%' refers to the top-right, then the 0s are bottom-right, and finally bottom-left.

```css
div {
  margin: 10% 0 0;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  border-radius: 100% 100% 0 0;
  // gradient generated with http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ using #81badd and #ae85ff
  background: rgb(129,186,221);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(129,186,221,1) 0%, rgba(174,133,255,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(129,186,221,1) 0%,rgba(174,133,255,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(129,186,221,1) 0%,rgba(174,133,255,1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#81badd', endColorstr='#ae85ff',GradientType=0 );
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of this solution. +1

Answer (score 1):

Some code like this may provide a way of your issue:

```html
<div style="width: 300px;height: 300px;overflow: hidden;border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;">
  <div style="background: #99A6E7; width: 700px; height: 700px; border-radius: 50%;position: relative;margin-left: -200px;margin-top: 150px;">
  </div>
</div>
```